# javascript post can't find php file in include directory

Tags: javascript, php

For security, I have gotten in the habit of placing php files in the default php include directory. On Red Hat based distros this is /usr/share/php. All my web page files (html php) find this directory with out problem. It is not even necessary to add a path to the file name.

When writing javascript, such as a form which POST to a php file, the script can not find php files in the php include directory. I'm guessing this is because of cross domain request or same origin policy? I'd rather not place the php files in the web site's directory. Is there a work around which won't destroy the security benefits of placing php files in the default include directory?

Comment: Where did you read that you should place all your PHP files in /usr/share/php? This is for shared libraries, not project code

Comment: I did not state that I place all php files in that location. The files which I place there are utility scripts which would for all intent purposes constitute 'shared libraries'. Placing them with in the web root could reveal program structure which may make hacking the site easier. I used to place them in cgi-bin and use a path such as ../../cgi-bin/myfile.php but found using the default include directory easier because the path does not need to be altered if the file resides in a sub-directory of the web root.

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript needs to be able to access these pages via a domain name. The PHP script must be public facing for JavaScript to find it. Is that directory accessible from example.com/path/to/php/script.php ? Once that is set up (either in Apache, nginx, IIS, etc) then you will need to point the JS to that location so it can access it.